# Remove groups of adjacent duplicates from list while preserving order

Tags: python, list, duplicates

There are a lot of similar question (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480214/how-do-you-remove-duplicates-from-a-list-whilst-preserving-order)) but I did not find anything that suited my needs.

My objective is to remove **groups of adjacent duplicates** from a list.
For instance, if my list is

```
['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'A', 'C', 'C']
```

my desired output is

```
['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'C']
```

i.e. every group of adjacent duplicates is removed, only one of their group remains.

---

My code so far involves a *for* cycle with a condition:

```
def reduce_duplicates(l):
    
    assert len(l) > 0, "Passed list is empty."
    
    result = [l[0]]   # initialization
    
    for i in l:
        if i != result[-1]:
            result.append(i)
    
    return result


l = ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'A', 'C', 'C']
print(reduce_duplicates(l))
# ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'C']
```

It produces the expected output, but I think there is a native, optimized and elegant way to achieve the same result. Is it true?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`groupby`](https://docs.python.org/fr/3.9/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) from `itertools`:

```
lst = ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'A', 'C', 'C']
out = [k for k, _ in groupby(lst)]
print(out)

# Output
['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'C']
```

**Update**

You can also use [`zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/fr/3.9/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) from `itertools`:

```
lst = ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'A', 'C', 'C']
out = [l for l, r in zip_longest(lst, lst[1:]) if l != r]
print(out)

# Output
['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'C']
```

Or without any imports:

```
lst = ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'A', 'C', 'C']
out = [lst[0]] + [r for l, r in zip(lst, lst[1:]) if l != r]
print(out)

# Output
['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'C']
```

Answer (score 0):

The itertools documentation provides a [recipe](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) for exactly this, `unique_justseen`. Since it uses map, it may be a tiny bit faster than the regular list comprehension, and also supports a key-function.

```py
def unique_justseen(iterable, key=None):
    "List unique elements, preserving order. Remember only the element just seen."
    # unique_justseen('AAAABBBCCDAABBB') --> A B C D A B
    # unique_justseen('ABBCcAD', str.lower) --> A B C A D
    return map(next, map(operator.itemgetter(1), groupby(iterable, key)))
```